# How XPath axes preceding:: and following:: work?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have always believed that the `preceding` axis contains all nodes that are before the context node in document order, excluding any ancestors of the context node, and also excluding attribute nodes and namespace nodes.

Recently I came across two published books on `XML`. On chapters about `XPath` and `preceding` and `following` axes, those authors didn't mention the nodes that I believed should be excluded from the definition of those two axes. They simply defined them as ALL nodes before and after contexts nodes, respectively.

I get confused, naturally. I don't (dare) normally doubt published books, especially things that I found on two separate books.

I undrrstand XML is an evolving technology. Has there been a change in the official or recommended definition that I missed?

Thanks for any help clarifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a matter of what you believe, it's a matter of what the specs say. The latest (3.1) version of XPath defines these axes at

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#axes

as follows:

> the following axis contains all nodes that are descendants of the root
>   of the tree in which the context node is found, are not descendants of
>   the context node, and occur after the context node in document order
>
> the preceding axis contains all nodes that are descendants of the root
>   of the tree in which the context node is found, are not ancestors of
>   the context node, and occur before the context node in document order

The definition has not changed over time.

Sadly, it's not unusual for books to simplify. On the other hand, you may have missed something in the books you were reading, you haven't cited them specifically, so I can't tell.

Comment: Thanks. I never got into the habit of reading offical specs. What you quoted is quite clear actually. As for the books, i didnt actually own them. So I can't give more information. They were charts / tables that I actually looked at. Given that I didnt read the entire books, I might have missed something. But given such a huge difference between the specs and what was said in the books, I would still call them mistakes. Even if they did mention it somewhere else, which should have been incorporated into the tables anyway.